# Using Python, get pixels inside a polygon

Tags: python, opencv, polygon, mask

I have a streaming image from a camera. From this streaming image, I've created a large set of polygons with each polygon being an 'area of interest'. I have then generated a mask using the polygons and applied that mask to the streamed image so now I only "see" the masked areas.

The question I now have is how do I figure out whether or not there is something inside my masked area (e.g. a rabbit, a person, a car, etc.) - note that it does not matter WHAT it is, only that the space is occupied.

I have found that a Laplacian spatial filter produces a pretty good visual of something being in a polygon or not (at least visually), but I have no idea what the next step would be. My thoughts are to average the pixels in the B&W image and if they cross a threshold then the assumption is yes, there is something there.

The file containing the polygon coordinates is laid out as:

```
x1,y1;x2,y2;c3,y3;x4,y4,...
x1,y1;x2,y2;c3,y3;x4,y4,...
x1,y1;x2,y2;c3,y3;x4,y4,...
x1,y1;x2,y2;c3,y3;x4,y4,...
x1,y1;x2,y2;c3,y3;x4,y4,...
```

My code to read the polygon array is as follows:

```
pointlist = []
data = open(args["slots"]).read().split()
for row in data:
    tmp = []
    col = row.split(";")
    for points in col:
        xy = points.split(",")
        tmp += [[int(pt) for pt in xy]]
    pointlist += [tmp]
slots = np.asarray(pointlist)
```

Image masking and filtering is as follows:

```
    img = cv2.resize(img, (480, 270))

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3, 3), 0)

    mask = np.zeros(blurred.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")

    cv2.fillPoly(mask,slots,(255,255,255))

    masked = cv2.bitwise_and(blurred,blurred,mask=mask)

    lap = cv2.Laplacian(masked, cv2.CV_64F)
    lap = np.uint8(np.absolute(lap))
```

It would be greatly appreciated if you could give me some example code of what to do next.

Comment: What do you want to do with the laplacian?

Comment: My thinking was to count the white pixels that that filter would give me. I would then compare the current white pixel count with the 'base' white pixel count and if it crossed a threshold, then that would mean I have something in that spot.